# How can I implement DHCP so that all users on a domain can get one pool of addresses and the rest get another?

Tags: dhcp

For example, having the domain users/machines on the 192.168.22.x subnet and the rest of the non-domain users and machines are on say, the 192.168.30.x subnet. I'm running Windows Server 2008 and the switches in the network aren't capable of 802.1x.

Comment: This really isn't something you can easily do.

Comment: @fzlogic What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You could use class-based assignment. The basic idea is that you could create a new User class on the DHCP server, with some identifier that you would assign to your domain-joined machines.

Then on each machine, you would set the User class ID: `ipconfig /setclassid "Local Network Adapter" "MyDomain"`

You could use a startup script defined in GPO to set that on each of the machines, or you can set each one manually, or set them remotely in a batch with some kind of scripting.

#### More info on using classes:

- [Create a New User or Vendor Class](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183644(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [DHCP User Class and Vendor Class Options](http://windowsitpro.com/networking/dhcp-user-class-and-vendor-class-options)

### Upgrade?

<s>If you can upgrade to Windows 2012 or 2012 R2, you can use Policies. This would easily let you look at the FQDN of the client and assign different addresses based on that. So you could define a policy that looks for `*.mydomain.net` and give those different addresses.</s>

This might not work if your non-domain joined computers and devices have their suffix set to the domain as well, but if possible this is a much easier way to go.

[It looks as though you cannot use FQDN-based policies to assign IP ranges.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/teamdhcp/2014/01/26/windows-server-2012-r2-enhancing-dhcp-policies-and-dns-registrations-in-dhcp-server/)

2012 [R2] will also give you neat DHCP failover/load balancing options that don't rely on clustering or 80/20 scopes.

Comment: Regarding your recommendation on using the policies in Windows 2012 / 2012 R2 - you cannot assign IP addresses based on FQDN. See this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/myu8Zf6.png and also here: ["Please observe that as the information message in the screenshot below suggests, you cannot configure IP address range or options for a policy with conditions based on fully qualified domain name."](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/teamdhcp/2014/01/26/windows-server-2012-r2-enhancing-dhcp-policies-and-dns-registrations-in-dhcp-server/)

Comment: @Goatmale that's good info and I've edited my answer; not sure that was downvote-worthy but that's your prerogative. The first part of my answer still applies.

Comment: No worries, I changed my vote - I just didn't want to spread misinformation on people having similar issues and needing a solution. I created a whole test environment thinking that was a possible solution, just to learn that this is not possible.

Comment: @Goatmale thanks, sorry to hear that you spent all that time in it